# How to query DateTimeOffset with DocumentDb

Tags: azure-cosmosdb

Assume I insert records into Azure DocumentDb of the following model:

```
public class Message
{
    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "tid")]
    public string Id { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "start")]
    public DateTimeOffset StartAt { get; set; }
}
```

They both automatically get stored as strings. I want to be able to query `StartAt`, so I added a RngeIndex on it. I used the Azure Portal to verify that the index works properly.

With that out of the way, I load up the DocumentDb .NET SDK and try the following query:

```
var since = DateTimeOffset.UtcNow.Subtract(duration);
return Client.CreateDocumentQuery<T>(Collection.DocumentsLink)
    .Where(m => m.AtStart > since)
    .AsEnumerable();
```

But I get the error

```
[DocumentQueryException: Constant of type 'System.DateTimeOffset' is not supported.]
   Microsoft.Azure.Documents.Linq.ExpressionToSql.VisitConstant(ConstantExpression inputExpression) +3204
   Microsoft.Azure.Documents.Linq.ExpressionToSql.VisitBinary(BinaryExpression inputExpression, TranslationContext context) +364
   Microsoft.Azure.Documents.Linq.ExpressionToSql.VisitBinary(BinaryExpression inputExpression, TranslationContext context) +349
   Microsoft.Azure.Documents.Linq.ExpressionToSql.VisitScalarLambda(Expression inputExpression, TranslationContext context) +230
   Microsoft.Azure.Documents.Linq.ExpressionToSql.VisitWhere(ReadOnlyCollection`1 arguments, TranslationContext context) +55
   Microsoft.Azure.Documents.Linq.ExpressionToSql.VisitMethodCall(MethodCallExpression inputExpression, TranslationContext context) +799
   Microsoft.Azure.Documents.Linq.ExpressionToSql.Translate(Expression inputExpression, TranslationContext context) +91
   Microsoft.Azure.Documents.Linq.ExpressionToSql.TranslateQuery(Expression inputExpression) +46
   Microsoft.Azure.Documents.Linq.SQLTranslator.TranslateQuery(Expression inputExpression) +20
   Microsoft.Azure.Documents.Linq.<ExecuteAllAsync>d__7.MoveNext() +177
   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task) +179
   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task) +66
   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ValidateEnd(Task task) +30
   Microsoft.Azure.Documents.Linq.<GetEnumeratorTAsync>d__10.MoveNext() +632
```

Is there a way to execute a type-safe query without changing the underlying model?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can perform range-query on dates, but not as a "type-safe" query.

This is because DocumentDB does not have a date time data type. Instead, DocumentDB adheres strictly to the [JSON](http://www.json.org/) spec for supported data types (String, Number, Boolean, Array, Object and Null). As a result, you get an exception, `Constant of type 'System.DateTimeOffset' is not supported`, when trying to query directly on DateTimeOffset using the LINQ Provider.

By default, the DocumentDB Client SDK serializes datetime object properties as an [ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) formatted string which looks something like this: `2014-09-15T23:14:25.7251173Z`. Adding a range index on strings would allow you to perform string range queries on the date. You could serialize `var since = DateTimeOffset.UtcNow.Subtract(duration);` as an ISO 8601 string to perform the query in your code snippet.

Check out this [blog post](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/blog/working-with-dates-in-azure-documentdb-4/) for a more in-depth discussion on working with dates. Please note that the blog is slightly out-of-date, as support for string range index and queries have been added since the time the blog post was initially authored.

Comment: I recommend testing by storing various times in various time-zones/offsets and ensuring ordering is as expected. It's just that comparing strings will work only if they're all in the same timezone, i.e. UTC ending `Z`. This conversion will discard the captured timezone/offset information which may be problematic for your application, worse, become problematic in future should you ever need to work out what the observed local time was of a historic event. Countries change their timezone rules over the years so it can be significant work. Apply caution on finance and audit apps.